# mimic web URL encode for Chinese character in python

Tags: python, url, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to mimic URL encoding for Chinese characters. For my use case, I have a searching URL for a e-commerce site

```
'https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword={}'.format('ipad')
```

When I search a product in english, this works fine. However, I need to have input in Chinese, I tried

```
'https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword={}'.format('耐克t恤')
```

, and found the following encoding under the network tab

```
https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?q=%C4%CD%BF%CBt%D0%F4
```

So basically, I need to encode inputs like '耐克t恤' into '%C4%CD%BF%CBt%D0%F4'. I'm not sure which encoding the website is using? Also, how to convert Chinese characters to these encodings with python?

Update: I checked headers and it seems like content encoding is gzip?

Comment: Check the headers (HTTP) and head (HTML) of the side to see which encoding it is using. It does not seem to be any UTF  encoding.

Comment: It says "content-encoding: gzip", is that a type of UTF encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding used seems to be [GB2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312)

This could help you:

```
def encodeGB2312(data):
    hexData = data.encode(encoding='GB2312').hex().upper()    
    encoded = '%' + '%'.join(hexData[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(hexData), 2)) 
    return encoded    

output = encodeGB2312('耐克t恤')

print(output)
url = f'https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?q={output}'
print(url)
```

Output:

```
%C4%CD%BF%CB%74%D0%F4
https://list.tmall.com/search_product.htm?q=%C4%CD%BF%CB%74%D0%F4
```

The only problem with my code is that it doesn't seem to 100% corrospond with the link you are trying to achieve. It converts the `t` chacaracter into GB2312 encoding. While it seems to use the non encoded `t` character in your link. Altough it still seems to work when opening the url.

Edit:

Vignesh Bayari R his post handles the URL in the correct (intended) way. But in this case my solution works too.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the library `urllib.parse` module. More specifically, `urllib.parse.urlencode()` function. You can pass the encoding (in this case it appears to be 'gb2312') and a dict containing the query parameters to get a valid valid url suffix which you can use directly.

In this case, your code will look something like:

```
import urllib.parse

keyword = '耐克t恤'
url = 'https://search.jd.com/Search?{url_suffix}'.format(url_suffix=urllib.parse.urlencode({'keyword': keyword}, encoding='gb2312'))
```

More info about encoding [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)
More info about urlencode [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Comment: Your code outputs  `https://search.jd.com/Search?{'keyword': '耐克t恤'}` instead of the inteneded link.

Edit: It was fixed in your most recent edit.